# Transformer circuit, equivalent impedance

Tags: impedance

Having trouble with a circuit on my problem set and was wondering if anyone wanted to give me a push.
[image]

*The ideal transformers winding relationship N1/N2 can be varied, as can the capacitance.*

*Decide the optimal ratio and the optimal value for the capacitance in order to maximize power dissipation in R2.*

We were given a hint to use the relationship

$$Z' = Z(\frac{N1}{N2})^2$$

Where Z is the impedance of the circuit to the right, and I'm assuming Z' is the impedance of the left circuit. But if these are the sans-tranformer impedances or if the transformer is affecting them, I don't know.

Grateful for a push...

Comment: Would also be grateful if anyone wanted to point out the English word for the "concept" we're touching on here, as I suspect my textbook uses unconvential naming. Is this an "impedance transformation"? Or "impedance matching"? Neither? Both?

Comment: impedance transformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maximize power into the resistors the inductive reactance needs to be cancelled by the capacitive reactance. This is because the circuit is series-tuned (despite the presence of the transformer).

You know the frequency (1kHz) and you know the inductance (1uH) and the natural resonant frequency for an LC circuit (series or parallel) is: -

\$F_N = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$

So then you transpose this to get the required capacitor value that would tune the circuit.

But your cap value is 1uF and this needs to be transformed to the value you have just worked out using the resonance formula. Does it need to increase from 1uF or decrease?

I suspect it needs to increase and so you have to decide by how much. Let's say it needs to increase ten thousand times to (say) 10,000\$\mu F\$, what should the turns ratio be to obtain this impedance transformation?

The hint in your question tells you that it is the square of the turns ratio that governs how this works so, if the required impedance transformation is 10,000 then the actual turns ratio is the square root of this.

I'll leave you to decide whether the turns ratio is 10,000:1 from left to right or 1:10,000. By the way 10,000 isn't the right answer - you need to calculate this.

Comment: So that's all I need to do? Make my capacitance fulfil the resonance frequency formula? That doesn't provide the correct answer... It's off by a factor of 10.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist What is the "correct" answer you have?

Comment: Well I mean I should probably have mentioned that the numerics in the schematic aren't correct. R2 = 1, R1=100, w=1000, L = 0.1. Using those numbers I got 1000 = 1/sqrt(0.1*C) <=> C = 10^-5, but the answer sheet said C = 10^-6, (with N1/N2 = 10)

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist undoubtedly a 10uF capacitor and a 0.1H inductor resonate at 159.16Hz and undoubtedly it is the turns ratio squared that determines impedance transformation and if the turns ratio is 10 then capacitor C1 must be 0.1uF. Please check the answer you have been given - it could be mistaken.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist - maybe the mistake is that the answer sheet said N1/N2 = 10 when it should have said \$(\frac{N_1}{N_2})^2\$=10.

Comment: Well... I scavenged the literature for clues and arrived at this: For maximum power in R2, (N1/N2)² times the impedance of the left hand circuit should be equal to the impedance CONJUGATE of the right hand side. So (n1/n2)²(r1+jwL) = r2+j/wC, which indeed gives C = 10^-6 and n1/n2 = 10. I'm not sure myself why that relation should hold, but it provided the correct answer. I'm at a loss...

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist L is 0.1H and w = 1000 therefore \$X_L\$ is 100 ohms. If the turns ratio squared is 100 then the reactance becomes 10,000 ohms and this equals \$\frac{1}{\omega C}\$. Therefore C = \$\frac{1}{1000 \times 10,000}\$ = 0.1uF as I said above.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a trick question.

When you understand that the inductor and the (transformed) capacitor form a series-resonant tuned circuit, which cause their impedances to cancel, you're simply left with the source resistance R1 and the load resistance R2, and their ratio determines the required turns ratio of the transformer.

After that, you simply calculate the actual value of the capacitor so that its transformed value resonates with the inductor at the source frequency.